# Draw Hasse diagram as two elements have same image

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, $P=\{y \in \mathbb N : y \text { is a prime number}\}$, consider the map $f$ defined as follows:
$$\begin{aligned} f:x\in S \rightarrow f(x) \in \wp (P) \end{aligned}$$ and
$$\begin{aligned} f(x)=\{y \in P: y \mid x\} \end{aligned}$$

Let $X=\{1,4,5,8,10\}$ and $f(X)=\{\{\emptyset\}, \{2\}, \{5\}, \{2\}, \{2,5\}\}$. Let $\Sigma$ be a partial order defined as follows:

$$\begin{aligned} x\text{ }\Sigma \text{ } y \Leftrightarrow f(x) \subset f (y) \text{ or } x=y\end{aligned}$$

draw the Hasse diagram relative to $(X, \Sigma)$.

The $f$ function clearly isn't injective, because $f(4) = f(8)=\{2\}$. I am unsure how the Hasse diagram should be drawn: in this case I have a repetition, so do I have to omit one of the elements with the same image element? So is my Hasse diagram correct?

[image]

Comment: You're specifying the domain and range of $f$, but not which elements map to what.

Comment: I suspect that $\subset$ is the notation for [strict inclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#The_symbols_.E2.8A.82_and_.E2.8A.83). Maybe you could check it in the text from which you took the problem. (BTW I think it is always good to mention the source of the problem in the post - give the name of the book, or a link, if they are available.)

Answer (score 1):

$\Sigma$ isn't a partial order since it lacks the antisymmetry property:
$$x \Sigma y \text{ and } y \Sigma x \Rightarrow x=y.$$
Here, $4 \Sigma 8$ and $8 \Sigma 4$ but $4 \neq 8$.

**Edit**: I just noticed that by $\subset$ you mean proper inclusion. In this case, $\Sigma$ is indeed a partial order. $4$ and $8$ are incomparable so you have to add a node labeled $8$ next to the node labeled 4 with connecting lines $1$-$8$ and $8$-$10$.

Comment: How do you get $4\mathrel{\Sigma}8$? Neither $\{2\}\subset\{2\}$ nor $4=8$ are true.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ has 5 particular elements, and *nothing* that goes on in the definition of $\Sigma$ can change which set $X$ is or what its elements are. The identity of $X$ is independent of what you do with it *after* defining it. So yes, you need to represent all of those elements in your Hasse diagram.

Also, no matter which strange functions you're using *internally* in the definition of $\Sigma$, what comes out of the process is just a particular subset of $X\times X$. This exact same relation could have been defined in various other ways -- at its most primitive you could just list all those pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a\mathrel\Sigma b$. Since what you're diagramming is the *relation itself*, rather than the irrelevant internal details of how the relation *arose*, you should not attempt to make the diagram encode information about $f$, except to the extent that this information influences the yer-or-no answers to "is this element related to that element"? The diagram *cannot* represent such information at all.